# Reverse proxy to port 8069 on Engintron issues while it works on standard NGINX setup

Tags: nginx

I have an Odoo app running on port 8069, and while this setup worked fine in my old server, my new server is using Engintron which seems to have a different method of working with vhosts. The standout issue is that under common_http.conf, this line becomes a duplicate of the vhost needed to run the app but is included in the automatically generated config that gets overridden whenever a new cpanel account is created, deleted, or when Engintron is updated.

What would be the correct way of setting this up properly within Engintron?

common_http.conf

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}
# This location / ends up getting included in the custom 
# vhost which is needed for all of the sites except this Odoo app.
```

custom_vhost.com.conf

```
upstream example{
 server 127.0.0.1:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream example-chat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name delegates.example.com;
    return 301 https://delegates.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name vendors.example.com;
    return 301 https://vendors.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com;
}
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name pgadmin.example.com;

# well-known_start
    location ^~ /.well-known {
        add_header Host-Header 192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024;
        root /home/example/public_html;
    }
# well-known_end
    ssl_certificate /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/*.example.com/combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/*.example.com/combined;

     add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
     add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
     add_header Cache-Control public;

    location / {
    deny all;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5050;
    }
}

server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com;

}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name vendors.example.com delegates.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 200m;
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    #proxy_set_header X-Odoo-dbfilter ^%d\Z;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;

# well-known_start
    location ^~ /.well-known {
        add_header Host-Header 192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024;
        root /home/example/public_html;
    }
# well-known_end

    ssl_certificate /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/*.example.com/combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/*.example.com/combined;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

# adds gzip options
    gzip on;
    gzip_types      text/css text/plain text/xml application/xml application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json text/x-json;
    gzip_proxied    no-store no-cache private expired auth;
    #gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    location /longpolling {
     proxy_pass http://example-chat;
     }

location ~* /web/static/ {
 gzip_static on;
 proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
 proxy_buffering on;
 expires 864000;
 add_header Cache-Control public;
 proxy_pass http://example;
}

location / {
 error_page   403  =  https://example.com;
 proxy_pass http://example;
 proxy_redirect off;
 gzip_static on;
}
# The above location becomes a duplicate of the previous default location - which in turn fails the validity of the configuration.

location ~* /web/content/ {
 gzip_static on;
 proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
 proxy_buffering on;
 expires 864000;
 add_header Cache-Control public;
 proxy_pass http://example;
}



location /web/database/manager {
 deny all;
 error_page 403 https://example.com;
 proxy_pass      http://example;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the conf files are added in alphabetical order, and any conflicting or duplicate settings are ignored - I ended up changing the name of the file so that it's included before the other ones. Also made the file immutable with the following command:

```
chattr +ai 1_custom_vhost.com.conf
```

I'm quite sure this is not a graceful solution, but it does the job for now.